# PHP within a ruby on rails application?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an unusual question.

I want to display a php file page within my ruby on rails application. So i want to put it in some random directory and under www.railsprojekt/phptestsite.php there should be just a independent file.

I don't get how i can do this, since everything has to be connected via routes.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What's the problem with using `rails`?

Comment: Most kinds of routing systems are set up to let any requests that directly match onto a physically existing file or folder through to begin with, and that’s probably also the case with a default rails setup … so not sure where exactly the problem is supposed to be here?

Comment: I recommend converting it man.  Essentially you could host that php on some other site and make a post request to it but as for integrating the two languages, I wouldn't do.  What is the reasoning behind this other than the laziness to not rewrite the page?